# React this.props don't update

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

Can someone help me to understand why this.props doesn't update after i filter it?

Here the slim version of my code

```
export default class AutoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      filterValue: 'all',
      isHidden: true,
      autoOptValue: ''
    }
  }

  handleOnChangeBrand(evt) {
    let selectedValue = evt.target.value;
    this.setState({optionValue: selectedValue});

    let filtered = this.props.autos.filter((auto) => {
      if(auto.brands){
        return auto.brands[0] === selectedValue;
      }
      return false;
    });
    console.log(this.props.auto) // still same number
    console.log(filtered) // less autos. Actual filtered array
  }

   render() {
    let autoDetail = this.props.autos.map(auto => {
      return (
        <Auto
          key={auto.id}
          id={auto.id}
          name={auto.name}
          brands={auto.brands ? auto.brands : false}/>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>

        <section>
          <select id='autoFilter' className={this.state.isHidden ? 'u-is-hidden' : ''} onChange={this.handleOnChangeBrand.bind(this)} value={this.state.autoOptValue}>
            <option value='brand1'> brand1 </option>
            <option value='brand2'> brand2 </option>
          </select>
        </section>

        <ul>
          {autoDetail}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

So basically i have this.prop.auto is an array of 100 auto, each of them is an object with brand (which is another array) with 2,3 brands each.

I was able to filter, since `filtered` give me back an array with filtered autos, the correct ones. 
But after that, this.props.auto doesn't update, nor does the UI.

I did something similar but sorting the auto by the brands and it works smoothly.
I don't get the difference here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.props` is effectively immutable within a component, so you cannot update the value of `this.props.autos`.  `Array#filter` is also a pure function, so the array being filtered is not altered, but a **new** filtered array is returned.  This is why when you log `filtered` in your function you see the filtered array, but `this.props.autos` is unchanged.

The simple answer to this is to do the filtering within your render method - I have added an initial state for `optionValue` of false, and within the filter method checked for this and not filtered if it is still false.

```
export default class AutoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      filterValue: 'all',
      isHidden: true,
      autoOptValue: '',
      optionValue: false
    }
  }

  handleOnChangeBrand(evt) {
    let selectedValue = evt.target.value;
    this.setState({optionValue: selectedValue});
  }

  render() {
    const { optionValue } = this.state;
    const autoDetail = this.props.autos
    .filter((auto) => {
      if (!optionValue) return true;
      if(auto.brands){
        return auto.brands[0] === optionValue;
      }
      return false;
    })
    .map(auto => {
      return (
        <Auto
          key={auto.id}
          id={auto.id}
          name={auto.name}
          brands={auto.brands ? auto.brands : false}/>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>

        <section>
          <select id='autoFilter' className={this.state.isHidden ? 'u-is-hidden' : ''} onChange={this.handleOnChangeBrand.bind(this)} value={this.state.autoOptValue}>
            <option value='brand1'> brand1 </option>
            <option value='brand2'> brand2 </option>
          </select>
        </section>

        <ul>
          {autoDetail}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: riight!! How could i not think about that! sounds great! let me test it :)

Comment: works perfectly, many thanks! i had the feeling it was not good to change this.props but i got mislead by the idea that also .sort() was giving me a new array, which instead it doesn't. Many thanks!

Comment: Definitely an inconsistency that `Array#sort` isn't a pure function, personally I wish it was!

Answer (score 0):

1. Filter returns a new array. This is so you still have the original on hand. There are so very, very many reasons this is a good thing, and practically 0 reasons it's a bad thing.
2. Props is meant to be immutable (just like arrays that you call filter on). Don't change the members on `props`. Nor should you change the members of the members of `props`, or any descendant data of `props` in general.
   That is why `state` exists, so if you absolutely *must*, you can save it there.

Regarding #2, typically you should be pulling that stuff out into higher and higher layers of abstraction, getting away from the view data, completely, and just passing in finished data that's ready for showing.

Answer (score 0):

The [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method always returns a new filtered array without changing the old one:

> The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

In your `handleOnChangeBrand` event, you're creating a filtered array, without affecting the old one, but then not using that filtered array when React calls render for the second time.

A small example of how you could handle this would be as follows:

1) Have react render your default `autos` prop

```
export default class AutoList extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const autoDetail = this.props.autos.map(auto => {
      return (
        <Autos ... />
      )
    });

    return (
      <ul>
        { autoDetail }
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

2) Add in a click handler and a state value to hold the value what you would like to filter by:

```
export default class AutoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      filter: ''  // this is where we will store what we want to filter by
    }
  };

  // All this function will do is update the state which we want to filter by
  // this 'arrow function' auto bind 'this' for us, so we don't have to explicitely set .bind as you were doing before 
  handleOnChangeBrand = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      filter: event.target.value
    })
  };

  render() {
    const autoDetail = this.props.autos.map(auto => {
      return (
        <Autos ... />
      )
    });

    return (
      <ul>
        { autoDetail }
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

3) Finally, we will use the value we are storing in state to filter to the auto brands we would like and use that to build our array

```
export default class AutoList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      filter: ''  // this is where we will store what we want to filter by
    }
  };

  getFilteredAutos = () => {
    // if we have no filter, return everything!
    if (this.state.filter === '') {
      return this.props.autos;
    }

    // this is returning the newely filtered array, without affecting the old one
    return this.props.autos.filter(auto => {
      if(auto.brands){
        // we're filtering by our saved value
        return auto.brands[0] === this.state.filter;
      }
      return false;
    });
  },

  handleOnChangeBrand = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      filter: event.target.value
    })
  };

  render() {
    // we're mapping by the filtered results here
    const autoDetail = this.getFilteredAutos().map(auto => {
      return (
        <Autos ... />
      )
    });

    return (
      <ul>
        { autoDetail }
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: this.props.autos is an array of autos coming from parent component. the logic of your solutions looks great but i'm wondering if it will just display an empty component before being filtered. Which instead should display the props.autos from parent

Comment: It shouldn't - you'll notice in the getFilteredAutos function that the first line checks for an empty state.filter. If it is empty, then it returns all of the autos to be displayed without filtering them at all